# about the Moore-Penrose inverse

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

In this [article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiD5Jbjyvb6AhWNRvEDHQvvAooQFnoECA8QAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Foperator.pmf.ni.ac.rs%2Fwww%2Fpmf%2Fpublikacije%2Ffaac%2F2013%2F2013-5-2%2Ffaac-5-2-8.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1UxerBHD0shooJFXybOinD)  , I found this proof :

> *If $A$ is a partial isometry, we know that $A^*=A^{+}$and $A A^*$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\mathcal{R}\left(A A^*\right)=\mathcal{R}(A)$. Thus, $A A^* A=P_{\mathcal{R}(A)} A=A$. Now, $A^4=A A^2 A=A$ implies $A^2=A^*$.*

which i don't understand why $A^4=A A^2 A=A$ implies $A^2=A^*$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect there is an easier argument, but here is one.

Write $$P=A^*A,\qquad\qquad Q=AA^*.$$ We know that $$A^4=A,\qquad\qquad A=QAP.$$
Write $T=A^3$. We have
$$
PT=PA^3=A^*A^4=A^*A=P.
$$
Then $$P=PP^*=PTT^*P.$$
This we can write as
$$
P(1-TT^*)P=0.
$$
Since $TT^*\leq1$ (this follows from the fact that $\|A\|=\|A^*A\|^{1/2}=1$), we get that $(1-TT^*)^{1/2}P=0$, and so  $(1-TT^*)P=0$, which we may write as
$$
P=TT^*P
$$

Thus
$$
(1-Q)P=(1-Q)TT^*P=(1-Q)QTT^*P=0.
$$
It follows that $P=QP$, so $P\leq Q$.

Repeating all the above with the roles of $A$ and $A^*$ exchanged, we get that $Q\leq P$. So $Q=P$. From here we can take two paths.

The first path is to notice that now $A=PA=AP=QA=AQ$. Then$$
A^2=PA^2Q=A^*A^4A^*=A^*AA^*=A^*. 
$$

The second path is to notice that $P=Q$ is $
A^*A=AA^*$,
and hence $A$ is normal. From $A^4=A$ we know that $\sigma(A)\subset\{0,1,\omega,\omega^2\}$, where $\omega$ is a primitive root of unity. Therefore $A^3$ is a normal operator with $\sigma(A^3)\subset \{0,1\}$, so $A^3$ is selfadjoint (a projection, in fact). Now we have
$$
A(A^2)A=A,\qquad (A^2)A(A^2)=A^2,\qquad (A\,A^2)^*=A\,A^2,\qquad (A^2\,A)^*=A^2\,A.
$$
Then $A^2$ is a Moore-Penrose inverse for $A$ and by the uniqueness, $A^*=A^2$.

Comment: why $A^2QA=A^2Q$?

Comment: That was wrong. I have changed the argument, please take a look.

Comment: Thanks..but $(1-TT^*)^{\frac{1}{2}} P=0$ it remains incomprehensible to me .. is that  because $(1-TT^*)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $P$ commute?

Comment: No. $$X^*X=0\implies X=0.$$

Comment: Thanks..I see now

Comment: Glad I could help. Please upvote if you found the answer useful. And not just my answer, but others that you use on the site, too. That's how it works  here.